# Show that $\ker(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}) = \mathrm{im}(f)$ for $f(x,y,z) = (x-2z,y,0)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is from an exam:

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $f(x,y,z) = (x-2z, y, 0)$. Show that
>   $$
> \ker(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}) = \mathrm{im}(f)
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \mathrm{im}(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}) = \ker(f).
> $$

I was able to show that $\mathrm{im}(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}) = \ker(f)$ (the second equation) but for the first equation I got that $\ker(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}) = 0$ and $\mathrm{im}(f) = \mathrm{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$.

Comment: Please give us some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to your question. Where does your question come from, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's from an exam,  the question is to show that $ker(f-Id_{R^3})=Im(f)$ and that $Im(f-Id_{R^3})=Ker(f)$, i was able to solve this $Im(f-Id_{R^3})=Ker(f)$ but when i try the other I got that $ker(f-Id_{R^3})=0$ but $Im(f)=span{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)}$

Comment: I edit the question to clarify your problem. I don’t know how you get that $\ker(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}) = 0$. I would be good if you included your calculations.

Comment: I hope that you give me the answer if you know it because i am not an expert in this field

Comment: And thanks for editing the question to be more clear

Comment: i have mentioned my mistake  thank you for your aid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about $\mathrm{im}(f)$, but you didn’t correctly compute $\ker(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3})$. Notice that
$$
 (f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3})(x,y,z)
= (x-2z,y,0) - (x,y,z)
= (-2z,0,z),
$$
so indeed
$$
\ker(f-\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3})
= \{(x,y,0) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}
= \mathrm{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}
= \mathrm{im}(f).
$$